# What shapes can be involved in equal-area tilings of finite polygons?

Tags: geometry

For any polygon P of integer area n > 1, let a tiling of P be an arrangement of n polygons each with area 1 such that they exactly cover P.  Call a tiling of P "optimal" if the sum of the perimeters of the n polygons is minimal.  Can every area 1 polygon be part of an optimal tiling?  If not, which ones can?

Comment: As a note, it seems obvious that every polygon that can be part of an optimal tiling for any P can be part of an optimal tiling for some P with area 2.

Comment: Let Q be any area 1 polygon. Let P be the area 2 polygon consisting of two copies of Q joined together at their shortest side. Then I think the only optimal tiling of P is splitting it into the two copies of Q. Unfortunately, this construction of P does not always work without overlapping. Maybe you could instead just put an area 1 triangle on the shortest side of Q, but even that is not guaranteed to have no overlap.

Comment: The construction by @JaapScherphuis doesn't always work. If Q is an equilateral triangle, then the optimal division of the rhombus P into two unit area pieces uses a circular arc.

Comment: Also, it doesn't work for a pentagram I believe - I think that two pentagrams joined on a side does have an optimal polyganal tiling, it just uses a different shape.

Comment: Oh well. I checked out @JohnSullivan's assertion, and a circular arc is indeed shorter. With a circular arc you get a cut length of 1.4472.. instead of 1.51967... . But it is not optimal - just a straight line cut perpendicular to opposite edges of the rhombus is even shorter, at 1.31607...

Comment: I think @JaapScherphuis's construction is likely to work when Q has nonacute interior angles at both ends of its shortest edge.

Comment: @JohnSullivan It works for some such shapes, but not all of them - consider the two polygons pictured in https://i.imgur.com/F1J40FC.png (apoligies for the poor rendition, the latter shape is meant to have seven sides, and the blue area is meant to be half of the shape's total area.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, an "optimal tiling" by your definition will not exist. Take for instance a polygon $P$ of area 2. The optimal subdivision into two pieces of equal area 1 is the solution to an isoperimetric problem within $P$, and will in general be given by a circular arc, each end of which meets some side of $P$ perpendicularly. Only if this arc degenerates to a straight segment (as if $P$ is a rectangle) will this be a polygonal decomposition. Otherwise (as if $P$ is a triangle) there are polygonal decompositions of $P$ (with increasing numbers of edges) that get arbitrarily close to this optimum, but no optimal polygonal tiling.

Comment: Huh, that's very interesting - but I don't think it actually changes the question at all.  Would that then disqualify any polygon without a pair of parallel sides connected by a straight line, then?